# how to undo the staging changes done by git rm?

Tags: git

The very first command is:-

```
git rm <file_name>
```

[image]

now I have seen many examples of git rm <file_name> but I am unable to use this command without the -f option supplied.
why can't I remove the file without supplying the -f option?

Another thing that I learnt is `git rm` is not a permanent update and it requires commit before updating. so now what if I do this,

1. create a new file file1
2. add this file to index
3. use `git rm`  command to delete this file. e.g `git rm -f file1`

now, how can I get back this file file1 again to my index?

Comment: You can't, you deleted it. Why are you performing these actions, what are you trying to do?

Comment: let's suppose i have created a new file and added some codes in it. i did git add . now i thought this code is not required so i deleted this file without committing. after sometime i realized that this file is actually needed. so how do i get this file again ?

Comment: You can try your editor's history or a file undeletion tool. In the future, commit first, then decide to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the reason that you have to add `-f` is because the file has been staged for commit and has not actually been committed.

If you have run `git commit`, so that there are no changes being displayed when `git status` is run.  Then you would be able to run `git rm` without a problem.